# I just installed LAMP on my Debian VirtualBox, how do I find out the IP?

Tags: linux, debian

I've just successfully installed LAMP with these commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install apache2
apt-get install mysql-server
apt-get install php5 php-pear php5-mysql
```

Now that I have it installed, I'd like to be able to connect via Terminal to it, but I have no idea what the IP is.

I've done `ifconfig` and

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep inet | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

and they return `10.0.2.15` but when I try to connect to it via Terminal using

```
ssh root@10.0.2.15
```

it's unsuccessful. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Did you install an ssh server?  `apt-get install openssh-server`

Comment: I've done that, no packages were installed and still cannot access it.

Comment: Try connecting as non-root user?  Also it is helpful if instead of saying "cannot access it" say what actually happened.  Connection refused?  Login invalid?

Comment: Sorry chief, I tried connecting as a non-root user and still nothing. By nothing, I mean it times out while trying to connect as the IP is incorrect. There is no option for login at all right now.

Comment: `10.0...` is a LAN address.  Is your workstation on the same LAN as your server?  You won't be able to access the server using this address if, for instance, the server is at school and your workstation is at home.